# What is the reason for encrypting Identity field under IPsec phase1?

Tags: firewall, network, ipsec

**Why Identity fields are encrypted in IPsec phase 1 around packet 5/6 ? provided that the Identity field contains IP of either end**. Does it has any significance ? Does it holds anything different then any end firewall IP?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Even if the identities equal the IP addresses there might be an added benefit to encrypting them, as a passive attacker won't see that that's the case. Because the identities could be different than the IP address of the endpoints (e.g. a FQDN or a Distinguished Name of a certificate).

Comment: Thank you for your update, Seems clear to me now..